# Is there any option to hide/ remove .hive files?

Tags: flutter, flutter-hive

When I used hive as local db in flutter, .hive files are generated in user's app-directory. Is there any way to hide or remove these files from the app-directory?

Answer (score 0):

You can remove file which contains the box and closes the box by using this method.
[deleteFromDisk](https://pub.dev/documentation/hive/latest/hive/BoxBase/deleteFromDisk.html)

Comment: But I need the data still there!. Is there any way?

Answer (score 0):

Use `path_provider` to store hive file in getApplicationSupportDirectory

```
Future<void> init() async {
  final path = await getApplicationSupportDirectory();
  await Hive.initFlutter();
  Hive.registerAdapter(UserAdapter());
  await Hive.openBox<User>(HiveConst.userDataBox, path: path.path);
}
```